# Client object model: orderby in camlquery doesn't work

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

I have a list on SharePoint 2010: (only showing the first item)

[image]

How can i get that list alphabeticly? I use a camlquery to try this but it doesn't work. I do get the list but it is in a random order. Am I doing something wrong?

```
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='DisplayName'/></OrderBy></Query></View>";

                ListItemCollection listItems = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(
                     listItems,
                     items => items.Include(
                         item => item.DisplayName,
                         item => item["WikiField"]));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Be sure 'DisplayName' is really the internal name of the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayName` property is

> A string that contains the item display name, which for a document
>   library item equals what the user types in the Name box of the item
>   form. The default value equals the original name of the uploaded file
>   minus the file type extension.

as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.displayname(v=office.15).aspx).

If you would like to order the items in a document library you can do it via

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/></OrderBy>
```